# MySQL: how not to repeat the column_definition for each column when adding multiple columns

Tags: mysql, command-line, addition, alter

I am running mysql 5.0. How do I write an SQL query to add new coloumns (all of the same type) to a table without repeating the coloumn type for each of them.

For example:

```
mysql --user=db_user --password=db_pwd -e "ALTER TABLE db_name.db_table \
ADD ( \
new_column_1 TEXT NOT NULL,
new_column_2 TEXT NOT NULL)"
```

In the example above the common type is `'TEXT NOT NULL'`. Note that the actual scenario has a lot more coloumns and not just 2 as specified in the example.

Summarily, is there a way to 'factorize' the common type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. Each column name should be followed with its definition.